# How do I model data containing movie titles to retrieve a list of movies by genre?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, denormalization

I have a question regarding data modeling in cassandra. I want to create a cassandra database with movies, actors, ratings etc. I already defined what my tables should look like and I want to create tables like movies_by_genre, movies_by_year, actors_by_movie, movies_by_actor and so on.
My movie data looks like this for example:

| ID | title | year | genres |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Top Gun: Maverick | 2022 | action, drama, adventure |
| 2 | Black Panther: Wakanda Forever | 2019 | action, sci-fi, superhero |
| 3 | Thor: Love and Thunder | 2015 | comedy, action, superhero, sci-fi |
| 4 | The Hobbit | 2012 | fantasy, roman |
| 5 | Mary Poppins | 1964 | children, musical |

So when I want to create the table movies_by_genre I want the genre as partition key and for genre "Action" an output like this for example:

| genre | title | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| action | Top Gun: Maverick | 2022 |
| action | Black Panther: Wakanda Forever | 2019 |
| action | Thor: Love and Thunder | 2015 |

So the genre is part of a list as you can see in the first table so every movie can have several genres. How do I have to define my data input for my tables to get the result I require? Do I have to make a single dataset for every genre a movie belongs to?

I'm glad if you can help me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd like to make a friendly request and ask that you paste the outputs in text instead of screenshots. A lot of the engineers who answer questions here respond during their free time on their mobile devices and screenshots are very difficult to read. It would make it easier to help you if you paste the text instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If your application needs to retrieve movies by genre then you should design a table that is (1) partitioned by genre and (2) rows clustered by the movie title.

For example, here's a simple example table that is designed for that specific app query:

```
CREATE TABLE movies_by_genre (
    genre text,
    title text,
    release_year int,
    duration int,
    director text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (genre, title)
)
```

With this `PRIMARY KEY (genre, title)` definition, each genre will have one or more rows of movies.

Here's an example query which retrieves 5 action films:

```
SELECT genre, title FROM movies_by_genre
  WHERE genre = 'action'
  LIMIT 5
```

And a sample output:

```
 genre  | title
--------|---------------------------------------------
 action | Black Panther: Wakanda Forever
 action | Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness
 action | The Batman
 action | Thor: Love and Thunder
 action | Top Gun: Maverick
```

Comment: thank you! But does it also work like this when a movie has several genres?

Comment: Yes. If a movie is belongs to multiple genres, then you need to insert an entry for that movie in the `movies_by_genre` table for each genre. Cheers!